# How do I print all array items on one line?

Tags: c

I have the following code which uses an array. When I run the program it shows the result 9 times on 9 different lines, but I want to show the result just once:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int sin_num[9];
    int num1;

    for (num1 = 0; num1 < 9; num1++) {
        printf("Enter your SIN number one by one:");
        scanf("%d", &sin_num);
    }

    for (num1 = 0; num1 < 9; num1++) {
        printf("%d \n", &sin_num[num1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I mean by one lines is that I just want the entire array to display only one time, not 9 times not even on one line like this:                                       array is 123456789

Comment: remove `\n`  and remove `&`  of sin_num[num1] from printf statement while printing array!! It should resolve it.

Comment: Removing \n will still display the entire array 9 times, I just want it one time. Thanks

Comment: `&sin_num` has the wrong type and is likely not what you want anyway.

Comment: In the "enter number" loop (with an annoying prompt for each digit), are you correctly entering your number *one digit at a time*, as suggested, or are you entering it 9 times?

Comment: enable compiler warnings -- enable compiler warnings -- enable compiler warnings -- enable compiler warnings -- enable compiler warnings -- enable compiler warnings -- enable compiler warnings -- enable compiler warnings -- enable compiler warnings ... This message is for all the new programmers who write code with obvious issues like `printf("%d \n", &sin_num[num1]);` which would have been pointed out by the compiler given that warnings were enabled. And also *check `scanf()`'s return value* x 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 issue in your program:

1. Read the [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) manual page

   ```
   scanf("%d", &sin_num);`
                ^^^^^^^ here, sin_num is array of int, so scan should take it into its element and not to its base address.
   ```

   replace it with index as shown below, scanf("%d", &sin_num[i]);

   ```c
   for (num1 = 0; num1 < 9; num1++) {
       printf("Enter your SIN number one by one:");
       scanf("%d", &sin_num[i]);
   }
   ```
2. Read the [`printf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) manual page.

   ```c
    printf("%d \n", &sin_num[num1]);
             /*     ^, here no need of & as you are looping over array. */
             /*        Correction => printf("%d \n", sin_num[num1]);    */

   for (num1 = 0; num1 < 9; num1++) {
       printf("%d \n", sin_num[num1]);
   }
   ```
3. To avoid multiple lines

   ```c
    printf("%d \n", sin_num[num1]);
            /* ^^ as per your requirement, you don't need every element on new line so it should be removed. */

   for (num1 = 0; num1 < 9; num1++) {
       printf("%d \n", sin_num[num1]);
   }
   ```

Comment: Please format your answer correctly to allow readers to read it.

Comment: I was formatting it, meanwhile you formatted it, Thanks again. :)

Comment: Don't worry, please try to learn more about markdown to give quality content and format answers.

Comment: The error I found as Nitin pointed was the "&" in my second printf. I can't believe I made such a silly mistake!

Comment: @JohnSmith: “In life, there are no mistakes, only lessons.” ― Vic Johnson, Day by Day with James Allen

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the "\n" in your second for loop.

```
for(num1=0; num1<9; num1++) {
    printf("%d ", sin_num[num1]);
}
print("\n");
```